# Vertical scrolling issue

Tags: bug, android-app

Occasionally there's a strange effect when scrolling:

[image: vertical scrolling]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)